# init function for initializing List in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, init

I am trying to give init function some extra handling using the if else conditions:

```
val allDates = List<String>(daysInMonth) { "0$it" if(it/10 == 0) else it.toString() })
```

This is not a valid syntax for the init function and there seems to be very little information on this out there.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Nvm, just needed to change the order to :
`val allDates = List<String>(daysInMonth) { if(it/10 == 0) "0$it" else it.toString() }`
Got used to python syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like your if statement is wrongly formated, try this

```
val allDates = List<String>(daysInMonth) {  if(it/10 == 0) "0$it" else it.toString() }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want declare first array allDates

the init for allDates like this

```
val daysInMonth = 30
    val allDates = arrayListOf<String>()
    for(i in 1..daysInMonth){
        if(i/10 == 0){
            allDates.add("0$i")
        }else{
            allDates.add("$i")
        }
    }
```